# Как клонировать массив объектов перед удалением?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Почему в `data: []` пустой массив?

И как после отправки полностью удалить копию из памяти?

```js
let items = [
  {ws: false, data: [1,2,3,4,5]},
  {ws: false, data: [1,2,3,4,5]},
  {ws: false, data: [1,2,3,4,5]},
  {ws: false, data: [1,2,3,4,5]},
];
let clone = [...items];
for (let i in items) {
  items[i].data = [];
}

console.log(clone);

function sendData() {
  $.ajax({
    url: '/',
    method: 'POST',
    data: { data: clone },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {},
    complete: function() {
      // удалить из памяти clone
    }
  });
}

// sendData(); // Отправка на сервер
```

Comment: "Почему в data: [] пустой массив?" --- а что должно быть?   и про какой `data`  идёт речь? Тут их несколько упоминаний

Comment: @Алексей про тот что в массиве `clone`, где ключ `data`

Comment: Почему data там по-твоему не должен быть пустым?

Comment: Нужно копия для отправки на сервер

Comment: А почему не отправить оригинал? Какая разница?

Comment: @SwaD в оригинале удаляются данные, нужно перед удалением создать копию и после отправки удалить из памяти эту копию

Comment: Потому, что `items[i].data` - хранит не массив, а ссылку на массив, а `clone[i].data` - ссылку на `items[i].data`. Иными словами, чтобы копировать объекты или массивы нужно юзать глубокое копирование. А оператор `...`  его не делает. Если сами не хотите писать клонирование, то например у *lodash* уже есть готовая функция

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для того, что бы склонировать массив объектов, на примере вашего кода, необходимо склонировать как сам массив, так и все элементы, которые представляют собой объекты.

```js
let items = [
    {ws: false, data: [1,2,3,4,5]},
    {ws: false, data: [1,2,3,4,5]},
    {ws: false, data: [1,2,3,4,5]},
    {ws: false, data: [1,2,3,4,5]},
];
let clone = [...items]; // Создаем новый массив
for (let i in items) {
    clone[i] = { ...clone[i] }; // клонируем объекты
    items[i].data = [];
}

console.log(clone, items);
```

Клонирование вашего массива, так же можно осуществить через создание функции, которая будет возвращать склонированный массив

```js
let items = [
    {ws: false, data: [1,2,3,4,5]},
    {ws: false, data: [1,2,3,4,5]},
    {ws: false, data: [1,2,3,4,5]},
    {ws: false, data: [1,2,3,4,5]},
];

function clones(arr) {
    return arr.map(item => {
        return { ...item, ...{ data: [ ...item.data ]}}
    });
}

let clone = clones(items);   

for (let i in items) {
    items[i].data = [];
}

console.log(clone, items);
```

Удалить переменную не получится, однако можно ее обнулить.

```
clone = null;
```

Если вы сможете реорганизовать ваш код так, что бы отправка данных была до обнуления основного массива, то сможете обойтись без создания переменной и клонирования массива.

Comment: А дальше вложенность? `clone[0].data.push(11);` - поломал ваше клонирование.

Comment: @doox911 Так я и не говорил, что это универсальный клонирователь. Примеры даны для той структуры данных, которая представлена в вопросе.

Comment: Ну тогда необходимо указать, что вы создаёте новые объекты, но ссылки остаются. А то он(пользователь) потом долго косяк будет искать или задаст новый вопрос.

Comment: @doox911 Разве клонирование не равно *новый*? Какие ссылки и где остаются? Про какой косяк вообще речь?

Comment: *Разве клонирование не равно новый?* - а что вы понимаете под клонированием в JS?

Comment: @doox911 Вопросом отвечать на вопрос - не культурно, как минимум. Клонирование - создание нового объекта с такой же структурой и данными, как у клонируемого. Так про какие оставленные ссылки речь и что за косяк?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140579/discussion-between-doox911-and-swad).